# How to create assetlinks.json when website is handled by multiple apps

Tags: android, json, deep-linking, applinks

In order to link my app with the web page in need to define assetlink.json like below.

```
[{
"relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "package name",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    [key]
  }
}]
```

My website having a number of modules, say example in a news site having separate sections like news, car review, garget review, horoscope/astrology, cooking, live tv etc. In this case, the news portal has android app for each module with separate android apps and whereas all the modules are under the single domain. Then how can we define our assetlink.json

Comment: This is not part of the assetlinks.json file. Instead, it must be defined in your app through multiple intent-filters.

Comment: But as per https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"], is part of assetlinks.json

Comment: Yes but this is never mentionned on the Android documentation and I suspect the Android framework to simply ignore this parameter.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Associating a website with multiple apps** (In answer to "How to create assetlinks.json when website is handled by multiple apps")

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#multi-subdomain

A website can declare associations with multiple apps within the same assetlinks.json file. The following file listing shows an example of a statement file that declares association with two apps, separately, and resides at https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.puppies.app",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}, {
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.monkeys.app",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

Comment: It's interesting, but i cannot realize, how two apps can handle same app link, if they both installed on one device. For me, there's old app, and the new one - they have different app id-s, and they both are added to assetlinks.json. But only old app is opened, when app link is clicked and both of them installed. How to solve this?

Comment: You can add filters on your intent on the AndroidManifest and use specific folders or subdomains to open specifically with that one app.

Comment: two apps can handle same link if you have different build version prod/staging

Comment: You could have two entries per app, one with the production SHA-256 certificate fingerprint and one with the debug.  That is one for the version in the app store and one for your dev version.

Comment: If you need to handle similar URLs, or the same URL conditionally depending on multiple apps being installed, one can use intent filter `priority` values.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element#priority

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement the correct answer, if you want different apps to handle different sections (folders) of your site, after adding your apps SHA256 keys to your domain, you should in the app it self create and intent-filter on the AndroidManifest to match the section that you want that app to open.

Something like this

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="somedomain.com" android:pathPattern="/section/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```